# Java Snake game. Why is this image being drawn in completely the wrong location

Tags: java

I am making a simple Snake game in Java, and i want to use an image rather than a g.drawOval for a cherry on my game board. The cherry's location in randomly generated each time the game loads, or the cherry is eaten.

If i use the g.fillOval method, the cherry gets drawn in the correct location every time, but if i use an image the cherry is being drawn in the incorrect location every time.

Here is an image of the drawn cherry with the EXACT same coordinates (i am using a Point to represent the cherry) but you can see the clear differences in location.

**The randomisation of the cherry's location is working as intended, it is a problem with drawing the image**

Here is the outcome of my code:

[image]

The red dot is the g.fillOval and is the **Correct location** for the cherry
The Cherry graphic is where my g.drawImage puts the cherry.

The X/Y for the above image is `Cherry X/Y: 49 : 27`

This is the code which renders the game:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;

import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Render extends JPanel {


    private static final Color BG = new Color(0);
    private static final Color SNAKEBODY = new Color(3380564);
    private static final Color SNAKEHEAD = new Color(16724736);

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(BG);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 700);
        Snake snake = Snake.snake;
        g.setColor(SNAKEBODY);
        for (Point point : snake.snakeParts) {
            g.fillOval(point.x * Snake.SCALE, point.y * Snake.SCALE,
                    Snake.SCALE, Snake.SCALE);
        }
        g.setColor(SNAKEHEAD);
        g.fillOval(snake.head.x * Snake.SCALE, snake.head.y * Snake.SCALE,
                Snake.SCALE, Snake.SCALE);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);

        g.drawImage(snake.cherryImg, snake.cherry.x,  snake.cherry.y, snake.cherryImg.getWidth(null), snake.cherryImg.getHeight(null), null);
        g.fillOval(snake.cherry.x * 10, snake.cherry.y * 10,10, 10);
        //debug line
        System.out.println("Cherry X/Y: " + snake.cherry.x + " : " + snake.cherry.y);

        String string = "Score: " + snake.score + ", Length: "
                + snake.snakeSize;
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        //simple math to center ish text.
        g.drawString(string, (int) (getWidth() / 2 - string.length() * 2.5f),
                10);
        string = "Game Over!";
        if (snake.over){
            g.drawString(string,
                    (int) (getWidth() / 2 - string.length() * 2.5f),
                    (int) snake.dim.getHeight() / 4);
        }
        string = "Paused!";
        {
            if (snake.paused && !snake.over){
                g.drawString(string,
                        (int) (getWidth() / 2 - string.length() * 2.5f),
                        (int) snake.dim.getHeight() / 4);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can andy body see why there is differences in the drawing on these lines:

```
g.drawImage(snake.cherryImg, snake.cherry.x,  snake.cherry.y,snake.cherryImg.getWidth(null), snake.cherryImg.getHeight(null), null);
g.fillOval(snake.cherry.x * 10, snake.cherry.y * 10, 10, 10);
//debug line
System.out.println("Cherry X/Y: " + snake.cherry.x + " : " + snake.cherry.y);
```

Comment: You don't appear to be passing the same coordinates? It looks like the image is at `(x,y)` and the oval is at `(x*10,y*10)`. Why would those two lines be the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your two positions.

Your fill oval is happening at `snake.cherry.x*10` while the image is drawn at `snake.cherry.x`   (SAME FOR Y)

Thats why the image is at 49,27 and the dot is at 490,270

Comment: Happens to everyone. Best of luck!

Comment: Is it possible you meant '+' ten and not '*'; lol I have done that before and it is quite easy to overlook, so don't feel bad :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that this is occurring because there is what I call: "Invisible Feather", in the image. What this is, is extra invisible pixels which have not been cropped on the outside of the image. Go into an image editing software, and crop the outside of the cherry to fit the image.

You can test this, by drawing the cherry at `0, 0`. If it is not directly in the corner, there is some invisible feather on the outside of your cherry.

**EDIT:**

I see by the answer above, that I was incorrect about what your problem was. I am going to leave this answer up in case anyone has the problem I have listed.

Comment: Appreciate the response, i was also not aware of this issue.

Comment: Good, so it wasn't for nothing :)